# Cannot Connect subdomain of route 53 to ec2 node js app

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, subdomain, amazon-route53, bad-gateway

[image: Getting 502 Bad gateway error after searching with domain]

But It's working fine with public IP as below
[image: server is running in public IP]

And I have created a subdomain with route 53 and then assigned A record with instance public IP
But when I ping the domain and IP it's getting request time out and all packets were lost. My application is node express app.So please it's a huge favor if anyone can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, I found that you're using Nginx as a Reverse proxy. So it might be because of your Nginx config

example your Nginx config may look like this,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.21;
    ...
}
```

**you've to update it to:**

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name subdomain.domain.com;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sam I have updated it already like below 

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name alpha001.woworderz.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}

Comment: @KrishanDKM your application is running on port 5000 right? then you are forwarding to 8080? I can find it from your config that you are forwarding to 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Yeah So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @KrishanDKM change it to 127.0.0.1:5000 and restart/reload nginx

Comment: Sure I'll try this. Should I reboot the instance? or is it enough to reload the nginx?

Comment: It's still the same. Anything wrong with my subdomain pointing?

Comment: @KrishanDKM No problem with subdomain pointing, if so then it won't reach your server at all. Please check Nginx logs for more information

Comment: Hi @Sam Sure I'll check. Thank you for your guidance.